# mongoDB: python code issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

could it be the wrong bottle version?

I lookeed in the sessionDAO file provided by the admins, and they do it the same as i do it;

the code:

```
def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        self.users = self.db.users
        self.SECRET = 'verysecret'
```

says:

[1] connect to the `blog` db
[2] select the `users` collection

and in the login code i have:

```
def validate_login(self, username, password):

        user = None
        try:
            # XXX HW 2.3 Students Work Here
            # you will need to retrieve right document from the users collection.

            password = self.make_pw_hash(password)
                    user = self.users.find({"_id":username,"password":password})
```

I know self, username and password; it should be a simple find by document, as i wrote it; I now see that there might be a indentation problem, wich i can see it only on stackoverflow, in notepad++ it's not there;

and:

```
def add_user(self, username, password, email):
            password_hash = self.make_pw_hash(password)

            user = {'_id': username, 'password': password_hash}
            if email != "":
                user['email'] = email

            try:
                # XXX HW 2.3 Students work here
                # You need to insert the user into the users collection.
                # Don't over think this one, it's a straight forward insert.

                self.users.insert(user)
```

I know self, username, password and email;

The document is prepared by default: `user = {'_id': username, 'password': password_hash}`

It should be a simple insert: `self.users.insert(user)`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, none; this is strange

Comment: If you run the mongo shell and execute `show dbs;` then `use blog;` then `show collections;` then `db.users.find();`, does anything look goofy in that series of commands?

Comment: Where are you connecting to the `blog` db in your code?

Comment: strange, but, when i run them, everything is ok; they all exist

Comment: in the __init__; acutally, they have a validate.py file, wich is encripted, and that code initialises the entire app

Comment: could this be a error on the software and not on the code?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. That's about as far as I know to debug this.

Comment: i deleted the file, and the app still runs; whats happening?

Comment: Whenever you make any change to the source code, you need to restart the server for those changes to take effect.

Comment: you don't say ... yes, they did say that a restart might be required ... so ... that sthe trick ... lets try

Comment: ok, the app started to work ... but because its now waaaay to customized, it fails; but now, i will get it to work. 10x

Comment: Well then... let's post that as an answer :)

Comment: so, always restart the server when you modify the code; also, read the session file, it contains usefull info; use find_one, search only by _id; and the insert, is a standard insert; hope ou get the answer right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make any change to the source code, you need to restart the server for those changes to take effect.

Comment: NEVER EVER FOGET THIS. i knew that my initial code was perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

`user = self.users.find({"_id":username,"password":password})`

to

`user = self.users.find_one({"_id":username})`